# Searching extracted data from a file, stored into an array for answers. IO

Tags: java, arrays, class, oop, io

I have successfully extracted data from 2 files and stored them in array objects in their respective classes. This is some of my data that i have stored in array objects:

```
2005,Arsenal,ManU,Arsenal,WestHam,Y,2,3,40000
2006,ManU,Chelsea,ManU,WestHam,N
2007,ManU,Arsenal,ManU,WestHam,Y,1,0,260000
2008,Chelsea,ManU,Chelsea,Swansea,Y,4,0,285630
2009,Chelsea,ManCity,Chelsea,Swansea,N
```

Each comma represents a different column. This is is my code to store it:

```
try{ 
Scanner kd = new Scanner(file);
    while(kd.hasNext()){
        String data = kd.nextLine();
        String [] values = data.split(",");
        String year = values[0];
        String wScore = "N/A" , lScore = "N/A", crowd = "N/A";

        if(inputYears.equals(year))
        {
        g.setPremier(values[1]);
        g.setLosing(values[2]);
```

I did as suggested by some of the users but the only problem now is im getting the winner as blank.For example:

```
    Year: 2005
    Premier:
```

It should be:

```
    Premier: Arsenal
```

Anyway i can fix that?

Comment: Use a CSV parsing library such as OpenCSV?

Comment: we havent been taught how to use that, so i am assuming that i cant use that.

Comment: Eh? Well, you'll have to use how to learn external libraries anyway if you want to do serious Java, so might as well start early ;)

Comment: If you have to use array, then you will have to use a loop to search for the user input in the array.

Comment: haha i'd be happy be to but im sure my teacher wont be giving me any marks if im not within the guidelines, he has done it before

Comment: Can you show your array(s) in which you store the extracted information?

Comment: i already put it in, its in the second code section

Answer (score 1):

Well, if the users are going to query only by the year, then you should have a **map** with the **year** as a **key**.

In the init phase, try doing something like this:

```
Map<String, ArrayList<String>> map= new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();

while(kd.hasNext()){
    String data = kd.nextLine();
    String [] values = data.split(",");
    String year = values[0];
    String premiers = values[1];
    //String otherStuff= values[2]; and so on

    ArrayList<String> temp= new ArrayList<String>();
    temp.add(premiers);

    //temp.add(otherStuff);
    map.put(year, temp);
}
```

Later on, you can query like this:

```
ArrayList<String> values= map.get(userInputYear);
String winner= values.get(0);
```

Comment: A custom class with the appropriate fields (years, premiers, etc.) would be preferred to an `ArrayList`.

Comment: thanks for your help but we arent allowed to use array lists and mapping, teacher is pretty strict about it.

Comment: Small problem with this: you are assuming there might be more than 1 team for the same year, which is fine. However your code initializes a new ArrayList every iteration, instead of checking if the Map already contains the key.

Answer (score 1):

No collections? Tough teacher you got there....

In the absence of a Map you could try creating a separate `getPremiershipChampion` method.

Like this:

```
public PremiershipYear getPremiershipChampion (String userYear, String[] kd) {

 while(kd.hasNext()){
   String data = kd.nextLine();
   String [] values = data.split(",");
   String year = values[0];

   if (userYear.equals(year)) {
       PremiershipYear py = new PremiershipYear();
       py.setWinner(values[1]);
       py.setRunnerUp(values[2]);
    // Set whatever you need to here...
      return py;
   }    
 }

return null;
}
```

...then call it like this:

```
PremiershipYear year = getPremiershipChampion (userYear, kd);

// Get the winner
if (year != null) {
   System.out.println("Winner for "+userYear+"="+year.getWinner());
}
```

Here is the `PremiershipYear` class:

```
public class PremiershipYear {

    private String winner;
    private String runnerUp;
    private String third;
    private String fourth;
    private String faCupWinner;
    private int someScore;

    public String getWinner() {
        return winner;
    }

    public void setWinner(String winner) {
        this.winner = winner;
    }

    public String getRunnerUp() {
        return runnerUp;
    }

    public void setRunnerUp(String runnerUp) {
        this.runnerUp = runnerUp;
    }

    public String getThird() {
        return third;
    }

    public void setThird(String third) {
        this.third = third;
    }

    public String getFourth() {
        return fourth;
    }

    public void setFourth(String fourth) {
        this.fourth = fourth;
    }

    public String getFaCupWinner() {
        return faCupWinner;
    }

    public void setFaCupWinner(String faCupWinner) {
        this.faCupWinner = faCupWinner;
    }

    public int getSomeScore() {
        return someScore;
    }

    public void setSomeScore(int someScore) {
        this.someScore = someScore;
    }    
}
```

You can muck about with this to make it more efficient e.g. make `kd` class level, but this should give you the general idea!

Comment: also, with the year, it also says to have output the corresponding score and everything else in that line, so my thought was to use parallel arrays but i have no idea how to use the array objects to achieve that.

Comment: wow thanks for your help man, appreciate it, just needed some guidance, been stuck forever.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Map`.
If you only have one year per line, use a `HashMap<String, String>` with the year as key and the  team as value.

If you have many lines with identical years, use a `HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>` with the year as key and the team**s** as values.

In the latter case, you must ensure the value is initialized. If not, you initialize it and ad d the current team. If it was already initialized, you get the value by year and add the current team to it.

Once you have the user input, you can query your `Map`'s key set...

- to verify it contains the user input, and if so...
- to display the team / enumerate every team listed for that year

Answer (score 0):

you could make a class to represent a record of your data

```
class Data
{ 
    private String year;
    private String winner;

    ...

    Data(String year, String winner) { ... }
}
```

then you can fill a Map which associates a year with some data which makes looking-up the year a bit easier.

```
Map<String, Data> m = new HashMap<String, Data>();

while(kd.hasNext())
{
    String[] arr = kd.nextLine().split(",");

    Data d = new Data(arr[0], arr[1])

    m.put(arr[0], d);
}
```

but even if you just had a `List<Data>` or `Data[]` etc you could still do something like

```
for (Data d : listOfData)
{
    if (d.getYear().equals(yearToFind)) return d;
}
```

to find the year